# initialize bitbucket repository with existing project using netbeans

Tags: netbeans, bitbucket

I have an existing netbeansproject (about 20 classes, java) which i want to manage using a private repository. So I choosed bitbucket (have an acount and repository). I initialised a local git repository (using netbeans).

How can i connect my project with the bitbucket repository using netbeans?

When i try to "push" it i get this error message "Cannot connect to the remote repository at https://OsmosisDJones@bitbucket.org/OsmosisDJones/inba.git"

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question, still if anyone needs the answer.

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin https://...
git push -u origin master
```

You can find this info on bitbucket after you create the repository.

Comment: How is your answer linked with `netbeans`?